# jquery if none selected from drop down

Tags: jquery

i had this code:

```
    $("#source_lang, #targ_lang").each(function(index, element) {

        if ($(this +'option:selected').length== 0) {
        //some code 
        }
        }
```

I want to display error messages when none of items on the lists is selected. 
This gives me no results(the error message doesn't show).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#source_lang, #targ_lang").each(function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex === 0) {
        //some code 
    }
}
```

or - without using the each - you could also check

```
if ($("#source_lang, #targ_lang").find('option:selected').length < 2) {
    ...
}
```

(this means that *at least* one select has not been selected)

Comment: thnx! this was very useful. :)

Comment: I think your second option fits the question better than the first!

Answer (score 3):

Use `find()`:

```
if ($(this).find('option:selected').length== 0) {
        //some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done bins for above solution, you can check demo link.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9m

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <select id="sel_country" multiple="multiple" size="4" class="select">
    <option value="India">
      India
    </option>
    <option value="USA">
      USA
    </option>
    <option value="UK">
      UK
    </option>
    <option value="England">
      England
    </option>
    <option value="France">
      France
    </option>
    <option value="Australia">
      Australia
    </option>
    <option value="Norvey">
      Norvey
    </option>
    <option value="South Africa">
      South Africa
    </option>
    <option value="Malesiya">
      Malesiya
    </option>
    <option value="Dubai">
      Dubai
    </option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="Get Selected Values" />
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var seloptions = $("select#sel_country").val() || "";
        if (seloptions != "") {
            $("#result").text(seloptions);
        } else {
            $("#result").text("You have not selected any option(s)..!");
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9m

Answer (score 0):

The selectedIndex is -1 when no action has been taken on the HTML SELECT Dropdown.

**HTML**

```
<select name="city" id="select-dropdown">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="4856">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="5684">London</option>
    <option value="5983">New York</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery :**

```
if ($("#select-dropdown")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
    alert('Please select City.');
    $("#select-dropdown").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Try it once. It will work.